Legend selection not persisting through animation or frame transition?
I have created an animated bubble chart - attempting to emulate something like the gapminder tool. https://www.gapminder.org/tools/#$chart-type=bubbles&url=v1
I have a legend that allows me to select a specific group from my legend.
In the first image I have not selected any specific age group and all bubbles are present.
Image 1
In the second imagine I have selected the 80+ age group and the bubbles for that group are present as expected Image 2
As I play the animation or scroll through the frame the legend remains unchanged (80+ is still selected) however all of the bubbles have returned.
Image 3
I was wondering if there was a way to ensure my legend selection persisted through the animation or frame change?
I have attempted to use the uirevision = TRUE to maintain the current state of the interaction however this did not work.
This is my current UI and server code
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactive Animated Bubble Chart"),
  
  # First row for inputs
  fluidRow(
    column(2, selectInput("xVar", "Choose X-axis Variable:", 
                          choices = c("Combined Crude DALY Rate" = "combined_crude_daly_rate", 
                                      "Total DALY" = "total_daly",
                                      "Combined Crude YLL Rate" = "combined_crude_yll_rate",
                                      "Total YLD" = "total_yld",
                                      "Combined Crude YLD Rate" = "combined_crude_yld_rate",
                                      "Total YLL" = "total_yll",
                                      "Age Group" = "combined_age_group"))),
    column(2, selectInput("yVar", "Choose Y-axis Variable:", 
                          choices = c("Combined Crude DALY Rate" = "combined_crude_daly_rate", 
                                      "Total DALY" = "total_daly",
                                      "Combined Crude YLL Rate" = "combined_crude_yll_rate",
                                      "Total YLD" = "total_yld",
                                      "Combined Crude YLD Rate" = "combined_crude_yld_rate",
                                      "Total YLL" = "total_yll"))),
    column(2, selectInput("bubbleSize", "Choose Bubble Size Variable:", 
                          choices = c("Combined Crude DALY Rate" = "combined_crude_daly_rate", 
                                      "Total DALY" = "total_daly",
                                      "Combined Crude YLL Rate" = "combined_crude_yll_rate",
                                      "Total YLD" = "total_yld",
                                      "Combined Crude YLD Rate" = "combined_crude_yld_rate",
                                      "Total YLL" = "total_yll"))),
    column(2, selectInput("bubbleColor", "Choose Bubble Color Variable:",
                          choices = c("Data Year" = "data_year", 
                                      "Combined Age Group" = "combined_age_group",
                                      "Disease Group" = "disease_group"))),
    column(2, selectInput("circleRep", "Circles Represent:",
                          choices = c("Disease Groups" = "disease_group",
                                      "Diseases" = "disease"))),
    column(2, selectInput("animationVar", "Choose Animation Variable:",
                          choices = c("Age Group" = "combined_age_group", 
                                      "Data Year" = "data_year")))
  ),
  
  # Second row for the plot
  fluidRow(
    plotlyOutput("animatedBubbleChart")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$animatedBubbleChart <- renderPlotly({
    # Reactively filter data based on user input
    reactive_data <- reactive({
      # Determine filtering based on the user selection in the UI
      if (input$circleRep == "disease_group") {
        # Filter to include only entries where 'disease' is NA (general disease groups)
        filtered_data <- combined_data1 %>%
          filter(is.na(disease))
      } else if (input$circleRep == "disease") {
        # Filter to include only entries where 'disease' is NOT NA (specific diseases)
        filtered_data <- combined_data1 %>%
          filter(!is.na(disease))
      } else {
        # Default behavior (if applicable), or handle other selections if needed
        filtered_data <- combined_data1
      }
      
      # Preprocess data to include a custom hover text string
      filtered_data <- filtered_data %>%
        mutate(
          custom_hover = paste(
            "<b>", get(input$circleRep), " (", get(input$bubbleColor), ")</b><br>",
            input$xVar, ": ", get(input$xVar), "<br>",
            input$yVar, ": ", get(input$yVar), "<br>",
            input$bubbleSize, ": ", get(input$bubbleSize)
          )
        )
      
      filtered_data
    })
    
    # Plotting the data with custom hover text
    p <- plot_ly(data = reactive_data(),
                 x = ~get(input$xVar), 
                 y = ~get(input$yVar),
                 size = ~get(input$bubbleSize),  # Used for visual representation
                 color = ~get(input$bubbleColor),
                 text = ~custom_hover,  # Use the enhanced hover text
                 key = ~get(input$circleRep),
                 frame = ~get(input$animationVar), 
                 ids = ~get(input$circleRep),
                 type = 'scatter', 
                 mode = 'markers',
                 marker = list(sizemode = 'diameter', opacity = 0.5),
                 hoverinfo = 'text',
                 hovertemplate = "%{text}<extra></extra>") %>%
      layout(title = "Interactive Animated Bubble Chart",
             xaxis = list(title = input$xVar, tickformat = ','),  # Formatting ticks with comma
             yaxis = list(title = input$yVar, tickformat = ','),  # Formatting ticks with comma
             showlegend = TRUE, hovermode = "closest")
    
    return(p)
  })
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
